# How to change visited post color, or put badge on it?

Tags: html, blogger, posts, visited

I was wondering if it is possible to use visited pseudo-class to change the color of visited post in blogger's home page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [:visited](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_visited.asp) CSS selector to select visited links.

```
a:visited { 
  color: pink;
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more please?
I mean, in my blog I have this:
".post-image-link" which handles showing the image that is in the post, on the home page.
so how I can combine both, so when a person visits the post and gets back to home page the image turn gray?

Comment: In your CSS you can use `.post-image-link:visited` to select all your previously visited links. Also, take into account that this property will only select anchors `<a>` that have an `href` attribute.

Comment: I have this class
```<a class='post-image-link' expr:href='data:post.url'>```
this is ok?

Comment: I suppose the `expr:href` attribute then generates an `href` attribute. So yes, I think it should work with that.

Comment: yes there is href when I inspect it, but I am not sure what to add more or do so I can control the color of the image after being visited:
https://fantarimo.blogspot.com
here is the blog, I hope you can look and tell me what to do.

Comment: You should add some custom CSS. [Here](https://support.pipdig.co/articles/blogger-add-custom-css/) you can find how to add CSS to Blogger. You can try with something like this: `.post-image-link:visited { opacity: 0.5; }` or any style you want. Hope this helps.

Comment: after some editing... it will change the image color and that's if it contained transparent parts (I put .post-image-link:visited to red), my question is, can't I use it to grayscale image I mean if it did not contain transparent parts?

Comment: Thank you for you help :) best wishes for you :)